# PHP Replace all values in the third column in a csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to replace some hyperlinks in a csv file, like this one: 
[https://assets.suredone.com/683987/media-pics/6164307j-gabriel-61643-proguard-steel-shock-absorber-for-select-chevrolet-gmc-models.jpg. Here is my code:][1]. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$in_file = 'gabriel-images-urls.csv';
$out_file = 'results.csv';

$fd = fopen($in_file, "r");

$new_array= array();
$toBoot= array();

while ($data = fgetcsv($fd)) {
echo '<pre>';
if (strpos($data[2],'media-pics') !== false) {

$data[2]=str_replace('media-pics','media-photos',$data[2]);
fputcsv($fd, $data);
// echo $output;

}

}
?>
```

The new link for example must look like this:[1]https://assets.suredone.com/683987/media-photos/6164307j-gabriel-61643-proguard-steel-shock-absorber-for-select-chevrolet-gmc-models.jpg. The goal is he "media-pics" substring to be replaced with "media-photos". At this point nothing happens in the file. I think this is because the file is open only for reading but I am not sure.

Comment: You should not try to read and write from the same file simultaneously here anyway, that is asking for trouble. You defined `$out_file = 'results.csv';` at the top of the script already, so open that in write mode, and use the resulting file descriptor in the fputcsv call, instead of the one you are reading from.

Comment: And if you want to have records that don’t have a match for `media-pics` to be carried over to your new file as well, then don’t wrap the writing part into that if condition. Actually, that if could rather be removed completely - just make str_replace call, that will replace if it finds a match, and just return the unchanged value otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not simply do a string replacement on the whole file rather than attempting to load and process each line of the file using `fgetcsv`?

```
<?php

    $srcfile='gabriel-images-urls.csv';
    $outfile='results.csv';


    $csvdata=file_get_contents( $srcfile );
    $moddata=str_replace('media-pics','media-photos',$csvdata);

    file_put_contents( $outfile, $moddata );

?>
```